# Is it possible to position an ARKit plane to the center of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have a plane I am trying to position using `SCNVector3`. I need to force the plane to show in the middle of the screen once it is detected so it can be seen at all times. I am only trying to detect the ground so multiple surfaces should not be an issue. I have tried many things like forcing the `SCNVector3` the be positioned using a `CGFloat` but it will not accept those parameters.

Comment: not sure what you want. You want to detect ground and place a plane on ground or on middle of your screen.

Comment: I want to detect the ground but only have the plane show in the middle of the screen. Like the center of the plane will be centered on the screen. I can show a picture if needed.

Comment: Yes that will be great

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your plane to the camera node (with z = -1) so it will always be visible and follow the phone's position + angles.